# Indexing Tag, Do we need one?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Bit surprised by this but we don't seem to have a tag for Indexing ? Possibly one of the most used words on here. 
I don't have the privilege to create tags so a question feels appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dunno - I would see indexing as being a subset of the existing gears tag.

I mean, can you think of any question about indexing that is not about gears/gearing?

Perhaps adding synonym from, indexing to gears is the right solution?

Comment: That's a fair point, but whenever it's a gearing / drivetrain issue 9/10th it almost always comes down to indexing. Synonym seems appropriate as you suggest

Answer (score 1):

No. Indexing has been the rule rather than the exception, for what, 25+ years?

People who want to talk friction will mention that.